# Manually triggered .change() not firing on select element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a js file running on an application where the user can use the keyboard to change the value of a select element (dropdown list).  When the user changes this value by clicking (the normal way before I added this file), code runs in the backend to change the view.  Because of this, when the user uses the keyboard, I need to manually call the change event, because it won't get called when the value is changed programmatically.  This is working fine in IE but won't work in Chrome.  This is the code:

```
onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 37) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate").focus();
        var myOpts = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate').options;
        var currIndex = myOpts.selectedIndex;
        var newVal;
        if (currIndex > 0 ) {
            newVal = myOpts[currIndex-1].value;
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate").val(newVal);
        }
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 39) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate").focus();
        var myOpts = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate').options;
        var currIndex = myOpts.selectedIndex;
        var newVal;
        if (myOpts.length > currIndex + 1 ) {
            newVal = myOpts[currIndex+1].value;
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate").val(newVal);
        }
    }
}
$(templateDDL).blur(function(){
    $(templateDDL).change();
});
```

templateDDL is just a variable containing the full selector name "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate".  I am getting to the blur event fine.  (tested using console) but the $(templateDDL).change() is doing nothing.

Comment: please properly format your code.

Comment: remember setting a value in select controls also trigger the change event of Select control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for asp.net controls as their id does change by asp.net markup generated you user jQuery selector endwith like this

```
$("[id$=templateDDL]").change(.....
```

If you want to this by jQuery only. Otherwise there are Control.ClientID

```
$("#<%=templateDDL.ClientID%>").change(....
```

and Also Asp.net has client static id mode.  ClientIDMode="Static" check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

All above for binding. For triggering please try this

```
$("[id$=templateDDL]").trigger( "change" );
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but he id for this control does not seem to change.  I am always getting the correct control. because the value does change.  I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.  I can't use Control.ClientID or static id mode, because I have no access to the ASP code.  Just the javascript on top.

Comment: Jquery 3.1.1.  I was under the impression that $.change() would only be for binding if a callback function was used, and with no arguments it would trigger the event.  Either way, I switched it to $.trigger() as per your example and it still did not work.

Comment: In Internet Explorer by the way, it does trigger the change() event exactly like I had it.

Comment: You want to trigger "change" event manually in chrome. Am I right??? can you put this on fiddle so ppls here can solve the issue easily for you

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I made a jsfiddle, but the only problem is that ASP needs to make a request to the server.  I don't think that can be simulated in Fiddle.  When I bound a simple reload event to the change event in JSFiddle, that worked fine.  But that still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: There seems that you  were missing the binding for dropdown, which I update in the fiddle, and key... also not binded to any control. So I put an alert in blur and change. Now when you change in dropdown then first change will be called and blur which in fact again call change by your logic. Please is that what you want here https://jsfiddle.net/vg2fm3rz/4/

Comment: This did not help.  The change event in your example is fired and picked up by JS, but not picked up by ASP.  This dropdownlist is an autopostback, so I needed the postback to be called on ASP (sorry if I could have explained that better).  Anyway, I found a workaround for it.  I created a fake button (not really fake, just an html button with display set to none), and anytime I need an ASP postback from Javascript, I can call the "click" function of that button, and so far it seems to work like a charm.  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use an external variable and bind everything together properly:

```js
var templateDDL = "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate";

$(templateDDL).change(function (e) {
  theOption = $(templateDDL).get(0).selectedIndex;
  $("#output").html($(templateDDL).val());
});

var theOption = 0;

function moveBy(x) {
  var total = $(templateDDL).get(0).options.length;
  if (theOption + x >= 0 && theOption + x < total) theOption += x;
  $(templateDDL).get(0).selectedIndex = theOption;
  $(templateDDL).change();
}

onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 37) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveBy(-1);
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 39) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveBy(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTemplate">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
<div>Output: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this, however, and it did not solve my problem.  This is successful in changing the value of the select element, but I am not trying to replace the "change()" function, just trigger it (so that ASP recognizes that the value was changed and can do its thing).